# SharePoint 2007: Is it possible to insert a Image map into a SharePoint List?

Tags: list, jquery

How do we insert a image map into a SharePoint List such that when we clicked, the image map pop-up (with the help of JQuery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found any way of doing it. Basically, it is by placing the variables such as the location of the image map, the coordinates and so on in the List.

Then using SPServices to retrieve the data and allow user to select. Once the user click a option, the image map and all information related to it will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Using calculated columns to write HTML](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/). It may help you to place image links, in place of text links.